# md5 token in hidden form field

Tags: php, forms, security

I read in more than one website about this method of protecting forms:

I add a hiddenfield:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
```

the token is generated by:

```
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

I do understand that this code is virtually unbreakable due to it's randomness.

What I don't understand is: why they include the token in a hidden form field which can be viewed in the html source?

Could then a user save the form and copy the valid md5 token to a fake version of the form and submit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is designed to prevent [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

The point is not to stop Alice visiting Bob's website, and then using the token to do bad things.

It is to stop Charles' website from using JavaScript to make Alice's browser submit a form to Bob's website and do bad things (with Alice's credentials). (Charles won't have a copy of the token to put in the form).

Comment: ok I like it and I will mark it as the answer. But then, how to prevent a legit user to use a form offline and change the data?

Comment: You make sure that any change they try to make is one that they are authorised to make.

Comment: I did this by checking that the answer contains only numbers (I am dealing with product IDs). But I wanted extra security by completely blocking fake data.. I guess that's just impossible then!

Comment: You would rather use “Malory” represent a malicious party.

Answer (score 0):

It is a strategy to help prevent [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). It doesn't matter that the token is in the HTML source, because it's only used once. The attacker would have to know what it is up front in order to trick the user, and even then the user has to have already brought up the form by legitimate means first.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is used to prevent [Cross-Site Request Forgery attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) where a malicious site is able to forge authentic and legitimate on the behalf of a victim when the victim is visiting a prepared web page of the malicious site. As the victim’s browser will send any authentication credentials along with the forged request, the server can’t distinguish whether the request was intended by the victim or not.

A simple example are `<img>` elements that cause the browser to send GET requests, another example are `<form>` elements that are automatically generated and send by JavaScript and can cause POST requests.

To mitigate this threat, this random token is used as a secret that is only known to the server and the browser: the server generates the random token, stores it in the session and issues it to the browser in the response that it then sends back in subsequent requests. Doing so, the malicious site isn’t able to forge legitimate requests as it doesn’t know the random token and isn’t able to get it.